# i am trying to get a ListView to show DataBase items but the items are all over the place

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

I have a school project that i need to make a android app for.

I am using Android Studio and Java to program it. I have a listview that displays items from my database but the items in the listview are not where i want them.

[It currently looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hwN9.png).

[But I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFIZG.png).

I would really appreciate some help.

I don't know where my problem is so I will include all related code. I am sorry if my English is bad I am not a native speaker.

And this is the first time i am writing a program in JAVA so if you see some rookie mistakes please let me know as well

**Edit**: my new and updated  content_Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listview"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/DatumVieuw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="57dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                tools:text="Halloo" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/watVieuw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp"
                tools:text="Mijn" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totTijd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/watVieuw"
                    tools:text="Is" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vanTijd"
                    android:layout_width="58dp"
                    android:layout_height="23dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="340dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/totTijd"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/watVieuw"
                    tools:text="Naam" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TotDatum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    tools:text="Ajaouin" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/VanDatum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    tools:text="Nataro" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="93dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="532dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
    android:onClick="btnClick"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="324dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="216dp"
    android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.375"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Edit**: The misaligned items:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/totTijd"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="22dp"
     android:textAlignment="textEnd"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/watVieuw"
     tools:text="Is" />
     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/vanTijd"
          android:layout_width="58dp"
          android:layout_height="23dp"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/watVieuw"
          tools:text="Naam" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/VanDatum"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="25dp"
          android:textAlignment="viewStart"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          tools:text="Nataro" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/watVieuw"
          android:layout_width="412dp"
          android:layout_height="47dp"
          android:textAlignment="textStart"
          android:textSize="24sp"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp"
          tools:text="Mijn" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/DatumVieuw"
          android:layout_width="419dp"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
          android:text="Halloo"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:textSize="30sp"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
          tools:text="Halloo" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/TotDatum"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          tools:text="Ajaouin" />
```

[image: I have this as my component tree]

**Edit**: I fixed the component tree it kind of works now

[fixed comp tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fLLa.png)

but now i have a new problem

[the new problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec9sf.png)

*Edit: new xml code

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listview"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/DatumVieuw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="57dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                tools:text="Halloo" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/watVieuw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp"
                tools:text="Mijn" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totTijd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/watVieuw"
                    tools:text="Is" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vanTijd"
                    android:layout_width="58dp"
                    android:layout_height="23dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="340dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/totTijd"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/watVieuw"
                    tools:text="Naam" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TotDatum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    tools:text="Ajaouin" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/VanDatum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    tools:text="Nataro" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

i added a constrained layout myself because my items would not keep their positions

Comment: Can you show us your `ListItem` view?

Comment: i only have a ListView everything i posted above is everything i have until now. if you mean the thing that go in the listview i have six TextViews  image 2 is the 6 Textviews

Comment: Which xml elements are the ones that are misaligned in the images you linked? I can't tell from your code because I don't fully understand Dutch ;-)

Comment: i tried to edit it so you can see clearer but its saying i cant post images but i just did :/

Comment: Then just tell me which xml element is the one that contains "Hallo", which one contains "mijn", which one "naam" and so on...

Comment: totTijd says Hallo, vanTijd says Naam, VanDatum says Nataro, watView says Mijn, Datumview says hallo and totDatum says Ajaouin

Comment: OK, first of all — in order to get more people to read your **entire** question — remove all the Java code, it is not related to your problem. You just have an xml layout which you want to look/align differently as it currently does. I recommend using a `CardView` with a nested `LinearLayout`. There you can add `TableRow`s which then include your `TextView`s. Take four `TableRow`s, because you want to split the view up into 4 separate vertical parts. Each one may have one or more `TextView`s as child(ren) and you need to align them properly, too.

Comment: thanks i got it to work only problem now is that you can see the empty cardview

Comment: Doesn't the `CardView` contain the mentioned layout elements? Edit the question and provide your new xml code, please.